# Split InDesign Poster in to Multiple Pages?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, paper, paper-size

Say I design a 34 × 44 inch poster in InDesign. If I don't have a big enough piece of paper, is there any way to split it up into four 8.5 × 11 pieces of paper? I want to then be able to tape them to each other to get the final poster. Is this possible? If so, how?
Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is a function of the Print output and is called "tiling". Check the print dialog box "General" section. There's no way to just divide an InDesign document into peices, it splits when printing.

[image]

If this fails, you could export your InDesign file to a PDF. Open a *new* InDesign document the size of the "pieces" you want, then place the PDF on multiple pages aligning them to the page edges where appropriate. It'll take some work, but could get you there. Print tiling is much easier though.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @CelloGuy  I was trying to :) There's an issue with stack's image host.. but i finally got one included.

Comment: it's still not working. I tried it without the `https://`, but my internet says blocked because of adult content. Will try later. Thanks!

Comment: @CelloGuy Maybe just the link: https://i.imgur.com/RNjoMi4.png ? (There's no adult content, I swear)

Comment: Back home. It works now...

Answer (score 0):

**InDesign Dialogue Box**

It is not necessary to change the size of your file, but you can tile your poster from the print dialogue box. Play around with the custom settings to get the best layout. For example, paper size, overlap size, automatic or auto justified.

[image: Indesign-print-dialogue-box]
**Acrobat Dialogue Box**

Alternatively you can tile from Acrobat. I find these settings a little easier to control.

[image: PDF-print-dialogue-box]